# How i can use LingPipe Tools to extract Arabic named entity

Tags: java, nlp, arabic, lingpipe

I'm trying to use Lingpipe tools to extract named entity recognition (Persons name) from Arabic text.
I was read a tutorial about this tools
http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/ne/read-me.html

how i can save the results in file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have no experience in this, but I just found [this](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/langid/read-me.html)  page in the website that you have mentioned, may it would be helpful.